# What's the best way to set an ngRepeat iterator outside of ngRepeat

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-scope

I have the following code, which is working well

```
<div ng-repeat="item in items">
   <ng-include src="itemView.html">
   <!-- ngincluded view "itemView.html" -->
     {{item.title}}
</div>
```

I now want to use itemView.html elsewhere in my app, **not within an ngRepeat**.

What is the best way to do this?

I realise that one option would be to create a new scope array variable `var singleItem=[myItem]`, and put a `<div ng-repeat="item in singleItem">` around that, but is there a more angular approach?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use ng-init.

main html:

```
    <!-- use it with ng-repeat  -->
<div ng-repeat="item in items">
    <div ng-include src="template.url" onload='myFunction()'></div>
</div>

<!-- using anywhere else in your code ng-init="item=item[index]"  -->
<div ng-init="item=items[1]" ng-include src="template.url" onload='myFunction()'></div>

<!-- template -->
<script type="text/ng-template" id="template1.html">
   {{item.title}}
</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

Since your item details is part of itemView.html template, it is independent. So it can be used anywhere in your app without any problem. 
To make you reusable template independent of the variable name item, you can wrap it in a directive like this:

```
module.directive('reusableItem', function() {
return {
  restrict: 'E',
  scope: {
    myItem: '=item'
  },
  templateUrl: 'itemView.html'
};
```

});

Replace all item reference with myItem in itemView.html.

It will be used like this:
    <reusable-item my-item="item"></reusable-item>
for your case.

A second use of this same directive may look like:
    <reusable-item my-item="itemXyz"></reusable-item>

What you would also like to do is caching your template if it is getting used at multiple place. To do that, you can use [$templateCache](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$templateCache).

Comment: you've missed the point of the question. The itemView template contains a reference to "item". Other than by wrapping it inside an ngRepeat, how do I set item?

Comment: Wrap your reusable template in a directive and pass the data you want to pass.